# Trying to develop a list view in Android with data in database

Tags: android, android-listview

Hi i am trying to populate a list view with data in the database but i am not able to make it out.Here is the code i tried out

**VehicleDisplay Class**

```
package com.android.allianz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class VehicleDisplay extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.vehicledisplay);

       SQLiteDatabase db = (new DBAdapter.DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
        ListView vehList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.vehcleList);
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT P_VEHMD FROM vehicle WHERE P_EMPID = ?", 
                new String[]{"i82112"});
        ListAdapter adap = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, 
                R.layout.vehiclerow, 
                c, 
                new String[] {"P_VEHMD"}, 
                new int[] {R.id.vehMdl});
       /* vehList.setAdapter(adap);*/



        Button bankaccount = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_vehicle);
        bankaccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View z){

                Intent bank = new Intent(VehicleDisplay.this,VehicleActivity.class);
                startActivity(bank);
            }
        });

}
}
```

My Database Class is

**DBAdapter Class**

```
package com.android.allianz;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBAdapter 
{ 

    public static final String V_EMPID = "P_EMPID";
    public static final String V_VEHID = "P_VEHID";
    public static final String V_VEHTP = "P_VEHTP";
    public static final String V_VEHMD = "P_VEHMD";
    public static final String V_REGYR = "P_REGYR";
    public static final String V_REGNO = "P_REGNO";
    public static final String V_INSNM = "P_INSNM";
    public static final String V_INSNO = "P_INSNO";
    public static final String V_INSVY = "P_INSVY";


    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "usersdb";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE4 = "vehicle";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;



    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE4 =
        "create table vehicle (P_VEHID integer primary key, "
        + "P_EMPID text, "
        + "P_VEHTP text, "
        + "P_VEHMD text, "
        + "P_REGYR text, "
        + "P_REGNO text, "
        + "P_INSNM text, "
        + "P_INSNO text, "
        + "P_INSVY text );";

    private Context context = null;  
    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) 
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    public static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
        {

            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE4);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion 
                    + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");

            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS vehicle");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }    


    public void open() throws SQLException 
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }


    public void close() 
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }    


    public Boolean AddVehicle(String P_EMPID,String P_VEHTP, String P_VEHMD,
            String P_REGYR, String P_REGNO, String P_INSNM,String P_INSNO, String P_INSVY)
{
Boolean bool = false;
ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
initialValues.put(V_EMPID, P_EMPID);
initialValues.put(V_VEHTP, P_VEHTP);
initialValues.put(V_VEHMD, P_VEHMD);
initialValues.put(V_REGYR, P_REGYR);
initialValues.put(V_REGNO, P_REGNO);
initialValues.put(V_INSNM, P_INSNM);
initialValues.put(V_INSNO, P_INSNO);
initialValues.put(V_INSVY, P_INSVY);

if( db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE4, null, initialValues)> 0)
{
bool = true;
}
else {bool = false;}

return bool;
}


    public boolean Vehicle(String vehtype,String vehModel,String purYear,String regisNo,String insurName,String insurNo,String insurVdty) throws SQLException 
    {
        Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE4 + " WHERE P_VEHTP=? AND P_VEHMD=? AND P_REGYR=? AND P_REGNO=? AND P_INSNM=? AND P_INSNO=? AND P_INSVY=?", new String[]{vehtype,vehModel,purYear,regisNo,insurName,insurNo,insurVdty});
        if (mCursor != null) {           
            if(mCursor.getCount() > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
     return false;
    }


}
```

The XML used are vehicledisplay.xml and vehiclerow.xml

**vehicledisplay xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/vehicledisp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ListView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:id="@+id/vehcleList" android:layout_height="377dp">

        </ListView>
        <Button android:id="@+id/add_vehicle" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:text="@string/addvehicle"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**vehiclerow xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/vehMdl" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Please kindly help me on this

Comment: Are you sure you are using the list adapter and database correctly?  Have you tried to populate the list with hardcoded values?  Have you tried listing out the database contents using LogCat?

Answer (score 1):

The problem that stands out to me here is that your table does not have its primary key column named `_id`. `CursorAdapter` uses this column internally to maintain consistency.

You should change the name of `P_VEHID` to `_id` (I recommend also adding `NOT NULL` to its specification) or add an `_id` column and add an index on `P_VEHID`.  Then change your select statement to read:

SELECT _id, P_VEHMD FROM vehicle WHERE P_EMPID = ?

Comment: The adapter is not working in the activitry can you help me on this

Comment: That would seem to be because you've commented out the line which sets the adapter to the list view.